# How to get ICredentials from a Cookie object

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, credentials

I can get an Authentication cookie from a SharePoint site that is not using AD for authentication. However, I want to use the PUT methos to upload a file and this asks me for a ICredentials object. How can get an ICredentials instance out of the Cookie object I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got the authentication cookie then adding the cookie on your WebRequest objects should work. I don't think that ICredentials object can be created from the cookie.

Comment: Yes, I actually followed this route. I used HttpWebRequest class and added a CookieContainer to it.